# How to identify user in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm using the on_member_update(before, after) event reference to see when the admins and moderators of my discord server go online and offline to monitor admin activity.
So far I can get my program to tell me someone goes online and offline and at what time but I can't identify which user is coming online and offline, so I get something like this:

```
User: has come online at {current_time}.
User: has come online at {current_time}.
User: has come online at {current_time}.
User: has gone offline at {current_time}.
User: has gone offline at {current_time}.
User: has come online at {current_time}.
User: has gone offline at {current_time}.
User: has gone offline at {current_time}.
```

So I have no idea who is coming online and going offline so for all I know it's the same person over and over again. How can i identify the member/user since there is no member parameter in the on_member_update() event reference.
If you need any clarification just ask.
Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    if str(after.status) == 'offline':
        print(f'User: has gone offline at {current_time}.'.format(after.name, after.status))
    if str(after.status) == 'online':
        print(f'User: has come online at {current_time}.'.format(after.name, after.status))
```

Comment: do you want to check whether user is online or offline using above data?

Comment: both, would you want me to show you the code?

Comment: it basically checks if the after status is different from before and if the after status changed to offline or online it tells me

Comment: You have `after.name` but you don't use it

Comment: all i need to find is how to identify the user for example in the on_message reference you can just do message.author to identify the user

Comment: why are you using `format()` an `f-strings`?

Comment: Both `before` and `after` are `Member` objects in the event. In `on_message`, `message.author` is also a `Member` object. So you can use the same type of code.

Comment: or i just want to know if its even possible because if it isnt possible it doesnt matter

Comment: oh ok thx @Benjin but how do i write the name

Comment: @deadshot the f-strings are so that i can easily add the user name/id and current time

Comment: Like I said, you have `after.name` but you never use it (you don't have a `'{current_user}'` in your strings). Maybe try `print(after.name)` as a starting point to confirm that it's there.

Comment: ok ill try that

Answer (score 1):

`after` is already a member object, if you would like to get the name, simply add `.name`:

```
if str(after.status) == 'offline':
    print(f'{after.name}: has gone offline at {current_time}.'.format(after.name, after.status))
if str(after.status) == 'online':
    print(f'{after.name}: has come online at {current_time}.'.format(after.name, after.status)) 

# Output: JohnSmith: has gone offline at some_time.
# Output: JohnSmith: has gone online at some_time.
```

If you would like to get the # number too you can use this:

```
if str(after.status) == 'offline':
    print(f'{after.name}#{after.discriminator}: has gone offline at {current_time}.'.format(after.name, after.status))
if str(after.status) == 'online':
    print(f'{after.name}#{after.discriminator}: has come online at {current_time}.'.format(after.name, after.status)) 

# Output: JohnSmith#1234: has gone offline at some_time.
# Output: JohnSmith#1234: has gone online at some_time.
```

- **before (User) – The updated user’s old info.**
- **after (User) – The updated user’s updated info.**

You can find the full documentation on the `on_member_update` event [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=update#discord.on_member_update) and the full documentation for the `discord.User` object [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=update#discord.User).